# Error performing arrange function on csv file data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a csv file containing data and I want to apply arrange() function to filter data in descending order. The data in the csv file is in the format Country;Gold;Silver;Bronze.

I the arrange() function and want to obtain the result of medals in 2022 Olympics in descending order (i.e. if number of Gold and Silver medals are equal then the country with hihest number of Bronze medals will be on the top. The code is written is:

```
c<-arrange(beijing2022Medals, desc(Gold), desc(Silver), desc(Bronze))
c
```

But I got this error when I run this code:

```
Error in `arrange()`:
! Problem with the implicit `transmute()` step.
x Problem while computing `..1 = Gold`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'Gold' not found
```

Then I tried this code again by using '' in the column names Gold, Silver etc by reading one of the answer of one question like this:

```
c<-arrange(beijing2022Medals, desc('Gold'), desc('Silver'), desc('Bronze'))
c
```

At this time I did not got any error but the arrange function did not applied.

Comment: Have you read the `.csv` as in `olympic_medals <- read.csv('~/path to my/file_name.csv', headers = (TRUE or FALSE), sep = ',')`. Hard to tell with the above. And welcome to Stackoverlfow.

Comment: `arrange`, like most functions on R work on data frames in memory, not CSV files(or other files) on your computer. If you just have a CSV file, you need to read it into R before you can do anything to it. If you have already read it in to R, call it a data frame, not a CSV file, because at this point it doesn't matter whether it came from a CSV file, an Excel file, a database, or anywhere else - now it's a data frame and if you continue to call it a CSV file it will be confusing.

Comment: If you have read it into R and it's a data frame, look at it `head(beijing2022Medals)` and make sure it looks right - are the column names and values what you think they should be? Posting the first few rows of it in your question will help us figure out your problem.

Comment: Posting would be `dput(head(my_olympic_medals, n =6))`, that will out put, on your machine `structure(...)`, and you would copy `structure(...)` and paste it above as an example of your data.

Comment: A minor point - assigning things to `c` is a very bad idea! :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it is difficult from your description to understand how/whether you loaded the data using e.g. `read.csv`. In any case, below is probably a working example of what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data retrieved from https://github.com/josephwccheng/olympedia_web_scraping
df <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwccheng/olympedia_web_scraping/main/data/Olympic_Games_Medal_Tally.csv")

df %>% 
  filter(year == 2022 & stringr::str_detect(edition, "Winter")) %>% 
  select(country, gold, silver, bronze) %>% 
  arrange(desc(gold), desc(silver), desc(bronze))
```